# Find an element by part of the href attribute

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to auto-open any contacts menu on the page:
as example I am going to "http://www.bawnlodge.co.uk/" page - then I would like to click on "Contact" tab

ATM I tried various approaches  like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'onta')]").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "onta")]').click()
```

(and few similar)

however so far, I was unable to click the element

I would be grateful if anyone could explain me why I am failing here :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a faster class or id css selector

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.menu-item-26 a'))).click()
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#menu-item-100 a'))).click()
```

You could also simply concatenate the string "contact" onto "http://www.bawnlodge.co.uk/" and .get to that. Multi word tab names are joined by "-" e.g. `lodge-bar-and-kitchen`. Everything is lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Try WebDriverWait and follwoing locator strategy.

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="right"]//ul[@id="menu-header-right"]//li/a[contains(.,"Contact")]')))
element.click()
```

You need to have following imports to work above code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

To invoke `click()` on the element with text as **CONTACT** using part of the `href` attribute  you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.container a[href*='contact']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='container']//a[contains(@href, 'contact')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```